# libmpi_mpifh.so.12: undefined symbol: mpi_conversion_fn_null_

Tags: mpi, openmpi, lib

I'm trying to run a new solver using the following command

ccx_preCICE -i Solid/flap -precice-participant Calculix

however everytime I get this error message ,, any thoughts??

symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12: undefined symbol: mpi_conversion_fn_null_

Output of `ldd /usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffef22b000)
libmpi.so.12 => /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1712/platforms/linux64Gcc63/openmpi-1.10.4/lib64/libmpi.so.12 (0x00007fe376a60000)
libopen-pal.so.13 => /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1712/platforms/linux64Gcc63/openmpi-1.10.4/lib64/libopen-pal.so.13 (0x00007fe376780000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe376550000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe376170000)
libopen-rte.so.12 => /opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1706/platforms/linux64Gcc63/openmpi-1.10.4/lib64/libopen-rte.so.12 (0x00007fe375ef0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe375cd0000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe375ac0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe3757b0000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fe375590000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe377000000)
```

Comment: You have a library issue.  Probably the incorrect version, unless you compiled it yourself?  You can use `objdump -tT /usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12` to view all the symbols in the library.

Comment: you can also `ldd /usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12`, it should resolve to `/usr/lib/libmpi.so.12`, otherwise you could have something wrong with your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet 
thanks for your comment; by running (ldd /usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12) i got the follwoing:

Comment: @Jason >> thanks for your help; however, I got a long list and I do not know if this can help me to define the problem. 
the printout stats with: 
/usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols


DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:

Comment: @Jason the symbol found in the list:
I found the symbol in the list as shown below 

0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              mpi_conversion_fn_null_


However, i still see the same problem.

Comment: Hey your answer should be an edit to the question since it is not an answer =D.  Anyway, I'm going to take a stab and say that the reference is supposed to be in libmpi.  If you run `objdump -Tt /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1712/platforms/linux64Gcc63/openmpi-1.10.4/lib64/libmpi.so.12 | grep mpi_conversion_fn_null_` you will not return anything (guess).  If that is the case you may just not have a compatible version of libmpi.so

Comment: your app is mixing the system fortran library (e.g. `libmpi_mpifh.so`) with the C library embedded in OpenFOAM(e.g. `libmpi.so`). do you have a `libmpi_mpifh.so.12` in `/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1712/platforms/linux64Gcc63/openmpi-1.10.4/lib64` ?if so, make sure this directory is at the beginning of your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

So for the sake of science I actually installed the standard package for this via `pacman` in Arch Linux.  I was able to find the symbol mpi_conversion_fn_null_ which is undefined for you.  That symbols implementation is actually in `libmpi.so.x`.  My libmpi.so installed to `/usr/lib/openmpi`, so I was able to check for this symbol with:

```sh
objdump -tT /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi.so | grep -w mpi_conversion_fn_null_

000000000009fc80  w   DF .text  000000000000000c  Base        mpi_conversion_fn_null_
```

The version of openmpi that I installed was 4.0.2 which resulted in my libmpi.so pointing to a libmpi.so.40.  I think we can safely assume that your libmpi.so.12 is version 1.2 which is quite a ways behind.

If you have the option, install a newer version of openmpi.  You could also [build it from source](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#easy-build) if necessary.